# Controlling the shape over another shape

Tags: cityengine

I have been using City Engine recently, I started working on writing a rule file and I am having problem.

I have created one shape where there is a Podium and tower above it[image: diagram of tower and podium]

I want to have enough control to be able to place the tower any place over the podium, which I am unable to do. Is there a way for me to have this kind of control over the placement of the tower.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is to split your shape before going into the Podium or Tower rules. Assuming you have rules `Podium` and `Tower` the rule might look something like this:

```
attr offset = 0
attr towerWidth = 0

Lot -->
    split(x) {
        offset : Podium |
        towerWidth : Tower |
        ~1 : Podium
    }
```

This will allow you to shift the tower along the x axis using the `offset` attribute while controlling the tower width using the `towerWidth` attribute.

If you want to position the tower in two dimensions you might consider using the [`shapeL`](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/topic/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/cgareference/op_shapeLUO.html), [`shapeU`](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/topic/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/cgareference/op_shapeLUO.html), and [`shapeO`](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/topic/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/cgareference/op_shapeLUO.html) operations. In all these applications you would use

`shapeX(...) { shape : Podium | remainder: Tower }`